# how to implement tag clouds in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, tag-cloud

I am creating a new site definition where I have to display the TAG CLOUD but unfortunately I am unable to get the tag cloud and I am not getting any clue how to do that. I tried adding Taxonomy field but it is not showing anything there.

Can someone help me in doing that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have done it by my own.. I have added the webpart inside my page and open that into the SPD. from there I copied the tag notation and pased in my default.aspx page. and it's working fine. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by my own.. I have added the webpart inside my page after publishing and open that into the SPD. from there I copied the tag notation and pased in my default.aspx page. and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

To create Tag Cloud

here is a way to create tag cloud using jQuery

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/how-to-create-a-3d-tag-cloud-in-jquery/

and there is a simple Flash based 3D TagCloud WebPart for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 available on codeplex

http://3dtagcloud.codeplex.com/

take a look.. :-)